# How to implement visual studio uml class diagram to vb.net class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, uml, class-diagram

I already make a uml class diagram on visual studio, how to implement it to vb.net class ?

Answer (score 0):

On your VB.NET project go to <kbd>Add...</kbd>><kbd>Existing Item</kbd> and from there select the `Class Diagram (.cd)` item from the General category.

This will add an empty design surface that allows you to either drag classes in from the Solution Explorer. You can also add new items from the Toolbox.

See also:

- [How to: Add class diagram to Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hyxd8c85.aspx)

  - This is using the technical class diagrams which are directly connected to the code.
- [How to: create UML Class Diagram from code.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff657806.aspx)*

  - This is using the 'functional' class diagrams which are more disconnected from the actual code.